# Como exibir/esconder algum elemento em Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css-display

Quero exibir e esconder os itens de uma lista quando o input for clicado. O código funciona se no css a tag ul tiver display:block, mas nao quando está display:none; que é o que eu quero.

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
    function fAbreGuias() {
    var vGuias = document.getElementById('guias');
        if (vGuias.style.display == "block"){ // se vGuias estiver escondido, exiba-o 
            vGuias.style.display = "none";
        }
        else{ // se vGuias for exibido, esconda-o
            vGuias.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<nav id="menu">
    <input type="image" src="_imagens/menuesboco.png" onclick="fAbreGuias()"/>
    <ul id="guias">
        <li>Guia 1</li>
        <li>Guia 2</li>
        <li>Guia 3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
ul#guias li {
    display: block;
}
```

A página precisa ser iniciada com a lista escondida, mas o código só funciona se ela começar com a lista sendo exibida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então, o seu **Javascript** está certo o erro aí é o seu **Css**, como você está pegando um elemento pelo **`id`**, não precisa pegar mais nada:

```js
function fAbreGuias() {
  var vGuias = document.getElementById('guias');
  if (vGuias.style.display == "block") { // se vGuias estiver escondido, exiba-o 
    vGuias.style.display = "none";
  } else { // se vGuias for exibido, esconda-o
    vGuias.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#guias {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <input type="image" src="_imagens/menuesboco.png" onclick="fAbreGuias()" />
  <ul id="guias">
    <li>Guia 1</li>
    <li>Guia 2</li>
    <li>Guia 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado! O problema era esse mesmo. Só não entendi porque funcionava com o display: block; e não com o display:none;

Comment: Então, sinceramente eu tbm não entendi, pode ser algo a ver com os nós dos seletores `ul > #guias > li`, alguma coisa age aí que faz apresentar o comportamento.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode definir uma classe ".hide" no seu CSS e depois no javascript fazer:

```js
    <script>
        function fAbreGuias() {
             var vGuias = document.getElementById('guias');
                  vGuias.addEventListener('click, function(){
                    vGuias.toggle("hide");
                    
                    //Esse método toggle ele coloca ou tira a classe no elemento html de acordo com o evento a qual foi atribuído na função
                  }
         }
    </script>
```

```css
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```