# Como verificar se um elemento está visível com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu ocultei uma div usando um arquivo CSS e em seguida tentei verificar se a div estava visível ou não com JavaScript, o meu código não retornou nada.
*Código usado:*
`document.getElementById("load-content-endereco").style.display`
Logo em seguida tentei adicionar o CSS diretamente na div, da seguinte forma:
`<div id="load-content-endereco" style="display:none;">Conteúdo aqui</div>`
E dessa forma o código funcionou.
Tentei buscar o termo em vários sites e todos usavam o mesmo exemplo, sempre adicionando o CSS diretamente na div com o atributo `style`.
Basicamente eu busco pegar valores e manipular o CSS que estão em arquivos CSS dentro e fora do meu servidor.
Alguém poderia me dá uma luz aqui?  Agradeço!

Comment: cara vc tem que fazer uma lógica, talvez com if else para ver se está com `.style.display = 'none'` etc. Na verdade não deu para entender bom o que vc realmente pretende fazer...

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como exibir/esconder algum elemento em Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/411764/como-exibir-esconder-algum-elemento-em-javascript)

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta, poderia explicar melhor, por favor?

Comment: Preciso apenas do valor que `display` recebe no momento da verificação.
Como falei, **estou definindo esse valor em um arquivo CSS** (`.../css/style.css`). Sei que adicionando o CSS diretamente na div  com atributo style (`style="display: none;"`) vou ter o meu resultado. Mas isso é o correto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse é o comportamento esperado.

Como você está setando a propriedade via CSS, esse valor não estará disponível ao tentar obtê-lo com Javascript usando `elemento.style.display` (a não ser que você defina esse valor, como disse ter feito). Você deve usar [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) para isto:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const display = window.getComputedStyle(div, null).display;

console.log(`Valor da propriedade display: ${display}`);
```

```css
div { display: none }
```

```html
<div>Elemento</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou bastante.

Comment: `getComputedStyle`  nem sabia que isso existia :D +1